# How can I toggle only one button at a time onclick?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, jsx

I'd like to know how I'd be able to toggle one button to green color one at a time onclick.  With my current code, when I click on one (with the intention of toggling one of them green), it toggles the other three buttons green as well.

Note:  `white-btn` and `green-btn` are CSS classes that I've defined.

I've made too many attempts to list here to try and rectify this.  What am I doing wrong?

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        white: true,
        smallSize: false,
        mediumSize: false,
        largeSize: false,
        xLargeSize: false,
    };
    this.smallClicked = this.smallClicked.bind(this);
    this.mediumClicked = this.mediumClicked.bind(this);
    this.largeClicked = this.largeClicked.bind(this);
    this.xLargeClicked = this.xLargeClicked.bind(this);
}

smallClicked() {
    console.log("clicked small");
    this.setState({smallSize: true, mediumSize: null, largeSize: null, xLargeSize: null, white: !this.state.white});
}

mediumClicked() {
    console.log("clicked medium");
    this.setState({mediumSize: true, smallSize: null, largeSize: null, xLargeSize: null, white: !this.state.white});
}

largeClicked() {
    console.log("clicked large");
    this.setState({largeSize: true, smallSize: null, mediumSize: null, xLargeSize: null, white: !this.state.white});
}

xLargeClicked() {
    console.log("clicked x-large");
    this.setState({xLargeSize: true, smallSize: null, mediumSize: null, largeSize: null, white: !this.state.white});
}

render() {
    let color_switch_size = this.state.white ? "white-btn" : "green-btn";

   return(
     <button className={color_switch_size} onClick={this.smallClicked}>Small</button>
     <button className={color_switch_size} onClick={this.mediumClicked}>Medium</button>
    <button className={color_switch_size} onClick={this.largeClicked}>Large</button>
   <button className={color_switch_size} onClick={this.xLargeClicked}>X-Large</button>
   );
}
```

Comment: We need to see how they are are getting the class applied.

Comment: @BrianThompson sure, just updated my snippet.

Comment: @testman you just need to put a extra condition in your className for example, `className={this.state.smallSize && color_switch_size}`, if the 1st condition is `true` then your class will be applied other wise not, see my detail answer

Answer (score 0):

A way to do that is to have a class for handling the clicked state, e.g., 'greenClas'.

For each button, you add that class in case it has been clicked or not.

```
 return(
     <button className={`buttonClass ${this.state.smallSize} ? 'greenClass' : ''`} onClick={this.smallClicked}>Small</button>

... 

   );
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd change a few things about how this is structured. I'd use a single change handler, and not use the `white` variable anymore.

Here's my suggestion:

```js
const initialValues = {
  small: false,
  medium: false,
  large: false,
  x_large: false,
};

.....

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {...initialValues};
}

// We'll use a generic handler that receives the button name
handleClick = (button) => (e) => {
  // Update the button to be the opposite of what it was before
  this.setState({[button]: !this.state[button]});

  // OR

  // If you want to restrict it to one white button at a time
  this.setState({
    ...initialValues,
    [button]: !this.state[button]
  });
}

// Separate this into its own function to keep render cleaner
getClassName = (button) => {
  // if button is set to true, use white
  if (this.state[button]) {
    return "white-btn";
  }
  // else use green
  return "green-btn";
}

render() {
  // Now each button has its class name managed independently
  return(
    <>
      <button 
        className={this.getClassName('small')}
        onClick={this.handleClick('small')}
      >
        Small
      </button>
      <button 
        className={this.getClassName('medium')} 
        onClick={this.handleClick('medium')}
      >
        Medium
      </button>
      <button
        className={this.getClassName('large')} 
        onClick={this.handleClick('large')}
      >
        Large
      </button>
      <button 
        className={this.getClassName('x_large')} 
        onClick={this.handleClick('x_large')}
      >
        X-Large
      </button>
    </>
   );
}
```

Comment: Hi Brian, a little unsure about how `handleClick = (button) => (e) {...}` should work .
Or did you mean to write `handleClick = (button) => (e) => {...}` ?

Comment: I did, and it has been changed

Comment: @BrianThompson do you think `e` is necessary here? `handleClick = (button) => (e) => {...}`, I think `handleClick = (button) => {...}` should be enough

Comment: It's not enough because the onClick passes an event. Our case here does not require the event, but it'll still be there. This type of change handler pattern also works great for text inputs, which do use the event. Whether we choose to disregard the event in an inline function or in a curried function is just up to preference.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my idea. I just add a small condition to verify the button before applying the style

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      white: true,
      smallSize: false,
      mediumSize: false,
      largeSize: false,
      xLargeSize: false
    };
    this.smallClicked = this.smallClicked.bind(this);
    this.mediumClicked = this.mediumClicked.bind(this);
    this.largeClicked = this.largeClicked.bind(this);
    this.xLargeClicked = this.xLargeClicked.bind(this);
  }

  smallClicked() {
    console.log("clicked small");
    this.setState({
      smallSize: true,
      mediumSize: null,
      largeSize: null,
      xLargeSize: null,
      white: !this.state.white
    });
  }

  mediumClicked() {
    console.log("clicked medium");
    this.setState({
      mediumSize: true,
      smallSize: null,
      largeSize: null,
      xLargeSize: null,
      white: !this.state.white
    });
  }

  largeClicked() {
    console.log("clicked large");
    this.setState({
      largeSize: true,
      smallSize: null,
      mediumSize: null,
      xLargeSize: null,
      white: !this.state.white
    });
  }

  xLargeClicked() {
    console.log("clicked x-large");
    this.setState({
      xLargeSize: true,
      smallSize: null,
      mediumSize: null,
      largeSize: null,
      white: !this.state.white
    });
  }

  render() {
    let color_switch_size = this.state.white ? "white-btn" : "green-btn";

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <button
          className={this.state.smallSize && color_switch_size}
          onClick={this.smallClicked}
        >
          Small
        </button>
        <button
          className={this.state.mediumSize && color_switch_size}
          onClick={this.mediumClicked}
        >
          Medium
        </button>
        <button
          className={this.state.largeSize && color_switch_size}
          onClick={this.largeClicked}
        >
          Large
        </button>
        <button
          className={this.state.xLargeSize && color_switch_size}
          onClick={this.xLargeClicked}
        >
          X-Large
        </button>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.state = {
    small: true,
    medium: true,
    large: true,
    xLarge: true,
}

changeColor = event => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: !this.state[event.target.name] });
}

getButtons = () => {
    const sizes = ['small', 'medium', 'large', 'xlarge'];
    return sizes.map(size => <button className={this.state[size] ? 'white-btn' : 'green-btn'} onClick={this.changeColor} name={size}>{size.toCamelCase()}</button>)
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.getButtons()}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve that like that a much easier way. Would that solution work for you?

```
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      smallSize: false,
      mediumSize: false,
      largeSize: false,
      xLargeSize: false
    };
  }

  onButtonPress = buttonName => {
    console.log('clicked  ' + buttonName);
    let myButtonsState = this.state;
    myButtonsState[buttonName] = !myButtonsState[buttonName];
    this.setState({
      ...myButtonsState
    });
  };

  render() {

    return (
      <View>
        <button
          className={this.state.smallSize ? 'white-btn' : 'green-btn'}
          onClick={() => this.onButtonPress('smallSize')}
        >
          Small
        </button>
        <button
        className={this.state.mediumSize ? 'white-btn' : 'green-btn'}
          onClick={() => this.onButtonPress('mediumSize')}
        >
          Medium
        </button>
        <button
        className={this.state.largeSize ? 'white-btn' : 'green-btn'}
          onClick={() => this.onButtonPress('largeSize')}
        >
          Large
        </button>
        <button
        className={this.state.xLargeSize ? 'white-btn' : 'green-btn'}
          onClick={() => this.onButtonPress('xLargeSize')}
        >
          X-Large
        </button>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Comment: This is actually mutating state. Change `let myButtonsState = this.state;` to `let myButtonsState = {...this.state};`. You probably won't see any bugs surface from it, but it should still be changed. If you `console.log(this.state)` after updating the value you'll see that it was already changed before calling `setState`.